# How to get mac address or serial number of windows phone 8.1 using c#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing windows phone application in 8.1 .
How do I get mac address or serial number of device.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ASHWID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/apps/jj553431(v=vs.10).aspx) to get device ID, but it is package related ID. If you need device ID which is not related to app package use the [AdvertisingID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.advertisingmanager.advertisingid(v=vs.10).aspx) but it's require more permissions.

Sample code to get ASHWID:

```
var token = HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
var hardwareId = token.Id;
var base64Hwid = Convert.ToBase64String(hardwareId.ToArray());
```

Comment: I already tried package related ID which is very long. I want a unique ID which is limited to 8 characters . so best is serial number or mac address. So is this advertising ID is unique and short?

Comment: It's not easy to pack unique ID to the 8 symbols. You can get ASHWID and calculate hash value based on this value.